# Schengen Visa from Seattle?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, spain

We are planning a vacation to Spain and I hear as Seattle residents we have to travel to San Francisco to obtain a Schengen visa.

Is there any other way around it?

Please note: I am an Indian citizen.

Comment: No. If you are in the catchment area of Spain's San Francisco consulate, you need to apply through them.

Comment: No probs, close voting as foundation research/travel agent

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way around that, if you are in the jurisdiction of Spain's San Francisco consulate, you need to apply through them